# How to write a unit test to cover custom PropTypes in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, code-coverage, react-proptypes

I have a reactjs component with a custom properties, that actually represents just a list of allowed extensions.

For example, my component can receive as a prop something like this:

```
<CustomComponent allowedTypes={['.pdf', '.txt']} />
```

and the prop types are defined like this

```
CustomComponent.propTypes = {
  allowedTypes: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    (propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) => {
      if (!new RegExp(/^\.[^.]+$/).test(propValue[key])) {
        return new Error(
          `Invalid prop ${propFullName} for component ${componentName}.`
        )
      }
    }
  )
```

I need to full cover the component with unit test, so also the code in the prop type definition must be covered.

I tried something similar, but it doesn't work

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.error = jest.fn()
});


it('should check wrong allowed types', () => {
  const wrongAllowedTypes = false
  try {
    const component = new CustomComponent(Object.assign(defaultProps, { allowedTypes: wrongAllowedTypes } ))
  } catch (error) {
    expect(console.error).toBeCalled()
  }
})
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest pulling out the fat arrow function and giving it a name. Then you can call it directly from a test.

Comment: `allowedTypes: PropTypes.arrayOf(CustomComponent.validateExtensionsProp),` is the new custom PropType and the method `validateExtensionsProp` is a static method in the `CustomComponent` itself. Once tested, 100% coverage is done. Thanks